# Better handlig of application properties file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In order to have the configuration file in the classpath in eclipse, I create it in a source folder. This way Eclipse automatically move it on the output directory and I can use

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")
```

to avoid using absolute paths. So far so good: I think is a good practice sort of, but please comment on this if there is something better. 
Then I want export a Jar file. Eclipse offer me an "Export as executable Jar file" that do a great job, but unfortunately, since it is a source, it pack the config file as well. I would obviously prefer the config file laying side by side to the jar so user can adjust settings. 
Now I do the following: Generate the ant file by an option of "export as executable jar" and modify by hand the ant to exclude the properties file. Too many manual steps, is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an ant script now there are no other manual steps than running this script in the future. Seems fine to me and this is what build tools are for.

But instead of this you could implement some kind of staged property lookup. First check if the properties file was passed as a program argument. If that is not available or was not passed take the one from the classpath as you do.

Comment: correct, but every time I change the project structure ( ie, using more external jar ) I have to manually add them in the ant script. I guess there should be something better.

Comment: If this question is more about your build system. You could change your include to `**/*.jar`, or better use Maven or Gradle for managing your dependencies.